# App after release not compatible with my device

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I recently posted my first app on google play store and when I wanted to download it on my phone I developed it on, the store said the device wasn't supported. When I checked the list of supported devices all of them were tablets, no phones.

[You can find the app here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thejuanandonly.schoolapp)

Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    package="com.thejuanandonly.schoolapp">

    <supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="480" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupWindow">
    </uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_pls"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/DefaultTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:largeHeap="true">


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ScheduleActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".TaskAdder"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SubjectDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".PictureGroupActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".NotesDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">

        </activity>

        <receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".NotificationRecieverActivity"></receiver>

        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".GridViewPager"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can we have some more details about your phone please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="480" />
```

Certainly doesn't look good in that setup.

Here's what the Android documentation has to say about this:

> Starting with HONEYCOMB_MR2, this is the new way to specify the
>   minimum screen size an application is compatible with. This attribute
>   provides the required minimum "smallest screen width" (as per the
>   -swNNNdp resource configuration) that the application can run on. For example, a typical phone screen is 320, a 7" tablet 600, and a 10"
>   tablet 720. If the smallest screen width of the device is below the
>   value supplied here, then the application is considered incompatible
>   with that device. If not supplied, then any old smallScreens,
>   normalScreens, largeScreens, or xlargeScreens attributes will be used
>   instead.
>
> Must be an integer value, such as "100".
>
> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
>   "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.
>
> Constant Value: 16843620 (0x01010364)

If you'd like to support phones as well, you should remove this line.

Comment: Thanks I will delete it and see if it helps!